# typeorm config with .env variables

Tags: node.js, typeorm

i have this ormconfig.json:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "db-pg",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "spirit",
  "password": "api",
  "database": "emasa_ci",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["dist/src/entity/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["dist/src/migration/**/*.js"],
  "subscribers": ["dist/src/subscriber/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "dist/src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "dist/src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "dist/src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

and have this env:

```
SERVER_PORT=4000
DB_HOST=db-pg
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=spirit
DB_PASS=api
DB_NAME=emasa_ci
```

but .env doesn't work in .json and so I don't know how I'm going to use my enviroment variables in my config orm

Answer (score 22):

There is a good [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/using-ormconfigjs).
If you want to dig into the source code - there is a class ConnectionOptionReader, which is looking for file `ormconfig` (with extensions `env`, `js`, `cjs`, `ts`, `json`, `yml`, `yaml`, `xml`) or for file `.env`. See the [load](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a09fb7fb919e7ebb1c174ba4b0abe09b245e0442/src/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.ts#L84) function for more details.

1 So the easiest way is to add a line in your `.env` file, like this:

```
TYPEORM_URL=postgres://user:pass@host:port/dbname
```

Or use this [sample](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a4dec02cc59d3219a29c7be0322af2253e1452dc/test/functional/ormconfigs/all/ormconfig.env). TypeORM will parse .env file using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).
[Here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a09fb7fb919e7ebb1c174ba4b0abe09b245e0442/src/connection/options-reader/ConnectionOptionsEnvReader.ts#L21) you can find all available env varibales.

2 If you read your `.env` file before TypeORM initialization, you can already use your env variables. For example in a Javascript file, instead `ormconfig.json`. Just export object like this from the file `ormconfig.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
    "port": process.env.DB_PORT,
    "username": process.env.DB_USER,
    "password": process.env.DB_PASS,
    "database": process.env.DB_NAME,
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": false,
    "entities": ["dist/src/entity/**/*.js"],
    "migrations": ["dist/src/migration/**/*.js"],
    "subscribers": ["dist/src/subscriber/**/*.js"],
    "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "dist/src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "dist/src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "dist/src/subscriber"
    }
};
```

Another [example](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a4dec02cc59d3219a29c7be0322af2253e1452dc/test/functional/ormconfigs/all/ormconfig.js)

Comment: They removed this part :/, now I'll have to CTRL + C from here? :(

Comment: Yep, ormconfig has been deprecated, see https://typeorm.io/changelog#breaking-changes-1

Answer (score 9):

Since [ormconfig is deprecated](https://typeorm.io/changelog#breaking-changes-1), I suggest another approach using TypeORM DataSource.

I'm using Heroku to deploy my server, so I created an environment file containing the same variable as created in Heroku Dynos, named `.development.env`:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/main"
```

Note that you can place this file anywhere in your project tree.

Then I created a datasource file:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

// Load env file
dotenv.config({ path: '../api/.development.env' });

DataSource definition
const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['../api/dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['./migrations/*.js'],
  subscribers: [],
});

export default AppDataSource;
```

This way, you can store in your environment your database connection settings.

Answer (score -2):

You could hide `ormconfig.json` and put your secrets directly in there, or viceversa, load TypeORM's configuration from your `.env` file. Is there a precise reason why you need them to be separated? If yes, then we can work out a solution.

Comment: becuase certain mappings of the ormconfig.json is specific to the project? Like the entities folder location etc. I have no clue how this "answer" has gotten upvotes. Segregating the actual potentially secret values to an environment file seems perfectly reasonable, and in my opionion - does not even require and explanation why it is better.

Comment: @JonasGrønbek – Agreed 100%. The entities and migrations folder is definitely not the same kind of configuration as e.g. the database password. How did you end up resolving this? I'm stuck on the same thing.

Comment: Configuration and secrets should change based on environment  you should avoid checking these in and deploying them as you can't 'hide' these values. Guessing the reason for using the environment variable approach is likely containerissition support.